# Linux script: Using perl to insert record using If-Else condition

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

I am working on a Linux bash script, and am trying to use perl to insert record(s) in a data file based on specific values present in the file.

Example: I have a data file that contains records: 00, 50, 51 and 52.

```
00 714
50OSDK10026-326455  NCIBLEX
51PO PO456
52GRW000000003200000
00 148
50OSDK15432-156831  HCIBLEX
51PO PO123
52GRW000000001500000
00 577
50OSDK19932-157431  SCIBLEX
51PO PO899
52GRW000000001500000
```

Position # 21 in record 50 contains the values: N, H, and S respectively. If the value = H, then I would like to insert record "##" above record 00 with the value: 945, else I would like to insert record "##" above record 00 with the value: 944. So the final file should look something like this:

```
## 944
00 714
50OSDK10026-326455  NCIBLEX
51PO PO456
52GRW000000003200000
## 945
00 148
50OSDK15432-156831  HCIBLEX
51PO PO123
52GRW000000001500000
## 944
00 577
50OSDK19932-157431  SCIBLEX
51PO PO899
52GRW000000001500000
```

I can insert the "##" record above the "00" record using perl as follows:

```
perl -i -pnle "print '## 944' if(/^00/);" datafile
```

However, I don't know how to check for pos: 21 in record: 50, and then use that value in the perl command to either print '## 944' or '## 945'.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '00 ';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @arr = split /\n/ or next;
    $arr[0] = $/ . $arr[0];

    my $rec = ( substr $arr[1], 20, 1 ) eq 'H' ? '## 944' : '## 945';
    print +( join "\n", $rec, @arr ), "\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

The script reads in records delimited by `'00 '`, and `split`s the chunk into an array.  It then uses `substr` to check the 21st char of the 50-record and the ternary operator to return evaluation results which are saved in `$rec`.  Finally, the array elements  and `$rec` are printed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that will do what you ask, but it's not very robust. It assumes that 50-records, if they exist, immediately follow 00-records. It also slurps the entire file as a single string (that's the `-0777` option) and thus assumes the input file is not too large.

```
# Shown on multiple lines for readability.
perl    \
  -0777 \
  -pe   \
  's/^(00.+?\n50.{18}(.))/$n = $2 eq "H" ? 944 : 945; "## $n\n$1"/gem' \
  datafile
```

A better approach would be to write a little parsing script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (my $line = <>) {
    if ($line =~ /^00/) {
        my $fifty = <>;
        my $n = substr($fifty, 20, 1) eq 'H' ? 944 : 945;
        $line = "## $n\n$line$fifty";
    }
    print $line;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I agree that a parsing script is a better option.